Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.DefaultHeaders$ValueValidator
this is the issue mentioned in the log

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cidAuthClient' defined in URL [jar:nested:/service.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/lk/dialog/mydialog/auth/externals/webclients/mife/CidAuthClient.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mifeAdaptor' defined in URL [jar:nested:/service.jar/!BOOT-INF/classes/!/lk/dialog/mydialog/auth/externals/webclients/mife/common/MifeAdaptor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webClient' defined in class path resource [lk/dialog/mydialog/auth/application/config/Beans.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient]: Factory method 'webClient' threw exception with message: io/netty/handler/codec/DefaultHeaders$ValueValidator

below is my pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.4</version> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>lk.dialog.mydialog</groupId>
<artifactId>authservice</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<name>authservice</name>
<description>Mydialog Auth Service</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <dockerfile-maven-version>1.4.12</dockerfile-maven-version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.15.0</log4j2.version>
    <cache-connector.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</cache-connector.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.26</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
        <version>24.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Wiremock for API mocking -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Sleuth for distributed tracing-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20231013</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--For logging with stack trace-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>lk.dialog.crm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>${cache-connector.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>33.3.1-jre</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.72.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring cloud dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <!-- SonarQube Plugin -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>deoployment</id>
        <name>Nexus repo</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>maven-central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>deployment</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>
            http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/
        </url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>deployment</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshot Releases</name>
        <url>
            http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/
        </url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

below is the webclient bean
@Bean
public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {

ConnectionProvider provider =
        ConnectionProvider.builder("customFixedConnectionPool")
                .maxConnections(maxConnections)
                .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(acquireTimeout))
                .build();

HttpClient httpClient =
        HttpClient.create(provider).resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);

return webClientBuilder
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();

}
below is the mifeAdapter class
package lk.dialog.mydialog.auth.externals.webclients.mife.common;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
public class MifeAdaptor {

private WebClient webClient;

private String mifeBaseUrlLive;
private String mifeBaseUrlStg;
private String mifeAppKeyLive;
private String mifeAppKeyStg;
private String mifeInitialAccessToken;

public MifeAdaptor(WebClient webClient,
                   @Value("${mifeBaseUrl}") String mifeBaseUrlStg,
                   @Value("${mifeAppKey}") String mifeAppKeyStg,
                   @Value("${mifeInitialAccessToken}") String accessToken,
                   @Value("${mifeLiveBaseUrl}") String mifeBaseUrlLive,
                   @Value("${mifeLiveAppKey}") String mifeLiveAppKey) {
    this.webClient = webClient;
    this.mifeBaseUrlStg = mifeBaseUrlStg;
    this.mifeBaseUrlLive = mifeBaseUrlLive;
    this.mifeAppKeyStg = mifeAppKeyStg;
    this.mifeAppKeyLive = mifeLiveAppKey;
    this.mifeInitialAccessToken = accessToken;
}

@Bean
public MifeAdaptorBase stg() {
    return new MifeAdaptorBase(webClient, mifeBaseUrlStg, mifeAppKeyStg, mifeInitialAccessToken);
}

@Bean
public MifeAdaptorBase live() {
    return new MifeAdaptorBase(webClient, mifeBaseUrlLive, mifeAppKeyLive, mifeInitialAccessToken);
}

}
I can not identify the reason for this issue.
if anyone know the reason and the way to fix this, would be a great help.
thank you.

You are mixing versions from Spring Cloud (remove the version tag from the dependencies), next to that Sprng Cloud 2020.0.2 isn't compatible with Spring Boot 3.x you need at least version 2023.0.2 for the bom (and remove the version tag from the Spring Cloud dependencie).
